# Insert into trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

i got a problem here , in MYSQL i have:

1-Table called "norte"  it has a column called "nortel"
2-Table called "bitacora" it has a column called "telefono"

im making a trigger for copying this information for example whenever i add something to "norte" table i want it to be automatically copied to bitacora table, i dunno what im doing wrong here´s my trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertar AFTER INSERT ON norte
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO bitacora SET telefono = NEW.nortel 
END;
```

the problem here is that it says unexpected END expecting';'

but if i delete the "END" it says

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertar AFTER INSERT ON norte
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO bitacora SET telefono = NEW.nortel;
```

> Unexpected END_OF_INPUT expecting ';'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter.

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER insertar AFTER INSERT ON norte
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO bitacora (telefono) values (NEW.nortel);
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Otherwise the DB thinks your trigger statement ends at the first `;` and then it would be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a " **;** " after the NEW.nortel:

It should be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertar AFTER INSERT ON norte 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO bitacora SET telefono = NEW.nortel; 
END;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1ee1/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thx for your; help i used the first answer and it seems it worked
anyways thx both for responding me :)  HAVE A GREAT DAY

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$


CREATE TRIGGER row_update_trigger  AFTER INSERT ON returns_loading_dc 
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO   Returns_receiving_Fc 
    set 
      Var_key=NEW.Var_key,
      Product_Title=NEW.Product_Title,
      Building=NEW.Building,
      Hub_ID=NEW.hub_id,
      JPIN=NEW.JPIN,
      Tagging_Required=NEW.Tagging_Required,
      Food_Non_Food=NEW.Food_Non_Food,
      Qty_loaded_from_hub=NEW.Total_Quantity_Loaded;


END $$ need help
```